# Delete logo at the start app in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

When my application start shows a white square. How can i remove/delete this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Package.appxmainfest** file,  clear out the splashscreen.

[image]

Comment: I would just add [Guides for splashscreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx) as an additional reference.